# xdebug Codeigniter in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, codeigniter, xdebug

I have Eclipse Indigo installed with Xdebug running a Codeigniter application.

The application runs correctly, but all variables (in the debugger) show up as Uninitialized

Anyone know if I need to configure something to get this to work?

Plain old PHP files work correctly.

---

Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2

Xdebug 2.2.0 Windows Binary for PHP 5.3 VC9 (32 bit)

Codeigniter 2.1.0

Thanks !

Comment: Which versions of PHP, Xdebug and Eclipse are you running?

Comment: Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2
Xdebug 2.2.0 Windows Binary for PHP 5.3 VC9 (32 bit) 
Codeigniter 2.1.0

Comment: You didn't mention the PHP version in there.